# In Java, how can I check input for a digit then letter?

Tags: java, input, passwords

I have a little issue with my Java program. I'm supposed to prompt the user for a distinct password pattern. I need the format DDLLDD (D=digit, L=letter) but I'm not quite sure how to approach this.

I've tread searching for questions similar but I've only found the ones where you're supposed to check if the input has a digit/letter in any order. I found some regex stuff too but I've never used those before, I've only gone with while/for loops to check for character input.

I've given it a try but I don't think I'm getting it. I tried checking each character index.

```
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = null;

    // Prompt
    System.out.print("Enter input: ");
    input = s.nextLine();

    // Check length
    while(!(input.length()==6))
    {
        System.out.print("Re-Enter input: ");
        input = s.nextLine();
    }

    boolean inputcheck = false;
    while(inputcheck)
    {
        char ch = input.charAt(0);
        char ch1 = input.charAt(1);
        char ch2 = input.charAt(2);
        char ch3 = input.charAt(3);
        char ch4 = input.charAt(4);
        char ch5 = input.charAt(5);
        boolean check = Character.isDigit(ch);
        boolean check1 = Character.isDigit(ch1);
        boolean check2 = Character.isLetter(ch2);
        boolean check3 = Character.isLetter(ch3);
        boolean check4 = Character.isDigit(ch4);
        boolean check5 = Character.isDigit(ch5);
        if((check==true)&&(check1==true)&&(check2==true)&&(check3==true)&&(check4==true)&&(check5==true));
        {
            inputcheck = true;
        }

    }
    System.out.println("PASS");
```

Comment: "digit" and "number" are synonymous; did you make a typo?  Does "L" in your pattern actually mean "letter?"

Comment: Ahh yes I apologize. I'll try to edit that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a pro with regex but this might suits your need :

```
\\d{2}\\D{2}\\d{2}
```

Basically it means :

```
\d //Any digit, short for [0-9]
{2} //Occurs 2 number of times,
\D //non-digit, short for [^0-9]
```

---

```
 do{
     System.out.print("Input: ");
     input = s.nextLine();
 } while (!input.matches("\\d{2}\\D{2}\\d{2}"));
```

You can learn more about regex [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/).

Comment: Oo, regex, didn't even think of that.  Nice.

Comment: The code finally works. Thank you, this is so much simpler than what I've been doing.

Answer (score 0):

Check your logic carefully.  Your code as shown appears to only "pass" passwords that are ALL digits.  Specifically, `check2` and `check3` probably need to be the opposite of what they are, either by:

```
boolean check2 = !Character.isDigit(ch2);
```

or

```
...&&(check2==false)&&...
```

Comment: Seems like I copied the wrong part for that. I meant check2 and 3 to be isLetter